# Eine Alternative für "by ear"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Ich stimme lieber meine Gitarren nach Gehör, als mit einem Stimmgerät
>   zu stimmen.

Was ist eine Alternative für "nach Gehör" ?

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative? And I wouldn't add *dem*, as @Baz, as I would say "Ich spiele nach Gehör."

Comment: Weil ich ein u. das selbe Wort in einem Satz nicht benutzen will.

Comment: Also have a look at [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gehoer) which lists `nach dem Gehör spielen` rather than `nach Gehör spielen`.

Comment: `Auditiv` wäre ein Fremdwort dafür. Ich kenne mich mit dem Stimmen von Instrumenten nicht so aus, aber macht man das nicht immer nach Gehör? Es klingt so, als ob du unterscheidest zwischen `selbst stimmen` und `eine Gerät stimmen lassen`.

Comment: Ich meine das Stimmen nach Gerät bedeutet, dass ein Gerät den Ton vorspielt, den man also gerade beim Benutzen eines Gerätes hört. Die Alternative wäre dann, dass man das sog. absolute Gehör hat, und aus der Erinnerung stimmt, gerade nicht nach Gehör. Dass Musiker einen unlogischen Sprachgebrauch pflegen, wie Juristen und Werbeleute, würde mich aber nicht überraschen.

Comment: @userunknown Das kann man zwar so machen, das ist aber relativ ungenau. Man kann selbst ohne absolutes Gehör ein Instrument stimmen, ob es dann stimmt steht aber auf einem anderen Blatt. Im Generellen haben Stimmgeräte heutzutage etwas ähnliches wie einen Zeiger. Dieser kann sowohl ein wirklicher Zeiger, ein angezeigter Zeiger oder gar eine Reihe LEDs sein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meines Wissens existiert kein Synonym für `nach Gehör`, das eventuelle Vorhandensein eines Fremdworts oder Fachbegriffs bleibt davon aber ausgeschlossen.

Comment: Das erklärt es. Danke!